# JQuery - Ajax - POST 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to send a Post request using jquery and it just won't work and always give me an
error:

`POST http://localhost:5500/api/orders 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

this is my code:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../../api/orders",
                data: {name: 'John', drink: 'Beer'},
                success: function (newOrder) {
                    console.log('success')
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Error Saving New Order");
                }
            });
```

this is my html directory: `localhost:5500/JsHtmlCss/JqueryAjaxTutorial/index.html`

this is where the json file is: `localhost:5500/api/orders`

The "Get" request works just fine but the "Post" request doesn't work at all:

Please Help Me I've been stuck in this problem for two days and I'm just new to jquery.

Comment: This seems not related to jQuery but to the API. The message says clearly `Method Not Allowed` which you need to create an endpoint for `POST` requests.

Comment: The answer to your question is in the error message you receive from the server: `POST `method is not allowed. You should set the http `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header to accept `POST` request. What language do you use for the backend?

Comment: It seems you're trying to POST to a static .json (text) file.   You need some server-side code to process the update to the json file, you can't just POST to it.

Comment: @adrian I think you have to define the POST method into api route if you are working with laravel or may be its because of haven't create an endpoint for POST requests

Comment: @everyone Thanks guys I think i know what the problem is, I don't know anything about backend  so it must be the endpoint thing that you are talking about